# PHP Specific Array Organization Function

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a few session arrays which I happen to be removing specific indexes from. For example, I have a session named `$_SESSION['products']`, this session has these elements: `$_SESSION['products'][0]`, `$_SESSION['products'][1]`, and `$_SESSION['products'][2]`.

I am trying to remove any one of those variables, the problem is when you remove the second variable, you mess up the array so that it cannot be displayed in a for loop. Is there a way to rearrange the following: `$_SESSION['products'][0]` and `$_SESSION['products'][2]` to `$_SESSION['products'][0]` and `$_SESSION['products'][1]` with a PHP built-in function? If not, is it even possible?

Comment: `it cannot be displayed in a for loop` Um, yes it can.  `foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $product)` will skip right over the missing key.

Comment: @Izkata: `foreach!=for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `array_values` **like**:

```
unset($_SESSION['products'][2]); // assuming the product key 
                                 // exist in product array sess


$_SESSION['products'] = array_values($_SESSION['products']);
```

**[Manual](http://au.php.net/array_values)**

`array_values() returns all the values from the array and **indexes the array numerically.**`

Comment: That works PERFECTLY, thank you very much! I had no idea that function existed! Thanks for making my day. :)